# What happens if I eat my own food in flight on an airline that prohibits outside food?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, food-and-drink, regulations

I have a long-haul flight with Scoot airline, and they have [this weird rule](http://www.flyscoot.com/en/fly-scoot/onboard/meals):

> Consumption of outside food and beverages is not allowed on board.

I've even read reports that Scoot flight attendants can actually ask passengers to put their food away.

I don't know what you think about this, but I'm going to bring some non-offensive sandwiches anyway. Now, what would be the worst-case scenario if a flight attendant asks me to hide my sandwich, but I disobey? I can't imagine any sensible way to prevent me from eating, given that I don't cause any distress to other passengers.

Comment: BTW at least I can claim that water is not a beverage: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beverage

Comment: The worst case scenario usually is that the crew decide decide your insubordination constitutes interference with their responsibilities, or signifies someone who is a safety/security risk, and you are met by authorities when you land who threaten you with criminal or civil penalties. While I think it unlikely it would come to that over a sandwich, the airline could impose other sanctions, since you had agreed to follow all their rules when you bought the ticket. Besides, the flight attendant didn't invent the rule; register your disagreement to management and in the marketplace, not on board.

Comment: Or better still don't fly on an airline whose rules you don't like.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan you have a point, but better alternatives would cost me around $200 more (I need only one-way ticket, but with higher quality airlines I'd have to pay for RT). If necessary, for $200 I'd choose to starve for 11 hours anyway.

Comment: For some part of an 11 hour flight I would expect the cabin to be dark and I would eat at that time. I had never heard of unbundling food from the deal on long haul before, although it's common on short haul.

Comment: @user16259 I think with Norwegian long hauls the meal isn't included, but at least they allow you to bring your own food.

Comment: Part of that $200 difference is that they are using food as a profit center, and get more profit if they limit people to their food.

Comment: On my previous trip I had a 9 or 10 hour Scoot flight and took a big bag of my favourite peanuts. I think I tried to hide them a bit. I didn't get in trouble. On my current trip I had a similar flight but decided to fast on the flight and have a rewarding meal at the Changi staff canteen when I finally got there. But I did look at the in flight menu and there was some food at prices that though inflated were not disgustingly overpriced.

Comment: @modular So why not fly Scoot to save $200 and buy a $10 in-flight meal? You'll still save $190 *and* you won't starve.

Comment: Could be problematic for those with dietary restrictions...

Comment: How do you know you wouldn't be causing distress to other passengers? Your food may be prepared in an area where peanuts are frequently used or contain them as an ingredient, resulting in a passenger with a peanut allergy having a severe reaction, for instance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In legal theory, disobeying instructions from cabin crew is a crime in most jurisdictions and you could theoretically be arrested.

In practice, and I say this having flown long-haul flights on Scoot a few times, the cabin crew is running around understaffed and has bigger things to worry about than inspecting whether your sandwich is authorised or not.   If you're still worried, eat during meal service right after the trolley has passed you, potentially deploying additional camouflage by purchasing an officially approved drink to wash down your contraband sandwich.

Answer (score 6):

Although rules are rules, this is a practical advice while flying with Scoot. I had done the same thing on Scoot.

Just buy something small from 711 or somewhere, not a full fledged meal. Airport security will not stop you. Just have the item once meal serving is finished. DO not try to eat while taking off or landing. Airline agents won't be looking to enforce that rule. However, if they say, please do not argue. Immediately put it away. Even the slightest aggression will be viewed as threatening the crew and police will be waiting for you when you land.

Another thing you can say is you have food allergies and you have to be really careful on what you eat. They won't usually argue with that.

*Note: Scoot's meal pricing is reasonable compared to food prices in Singapore, if it is prebooked.*

Answer (score 3):

Just don't take a whole pile of McDonalds or KFC on board. At Changi even flights to Oz now don't get screened at the aircraft door. I've never been asked to put a sandwich away. Subway might be a little risky though. But this is how they get you in SE Asia which is pedantic about T&C's. Yes strictly legally you are disobeying a crew order. That's actually where they can get you. Doesn't matter if its about food or anything else. instructions are instructions. So they make it about food. Its a dirty and nasty money grabbing tactic that exploits these loopholes that the national laws of SEA countries inadvertently allow this to happen.

Comment: Not everyone is out to get you... The crew would be the one dealing with your food poisoning when you eat some rotten food that you brought on board despite clear instructions not to.

Comment: In this case, it is a budget airline. Food is not free. So, its a loss of revenue if passengers bring their own food. Simple reason.